# When will OnSend be available for MAC?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

OnSend for OWA is already available for over a year and since then the microsoft documentation says 'will be available for other platforms soon'. Since then there has been no updates. Can somebody please give an update about the status; is it in development, when will it be released, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OnSend for Mac is currently under development, but we don't have a release date yet. You can roughly expect it in the next quarter.

Comment: Thanks! Next quarter meaning first quarter 2019 then, right?
Is there someway to track the progress without having to ask here? :)

Comment: This feature will be available by end of this quarter. Yes, you can reach out to us here for questions on feature releases. We do not have an upcoming features section on our API docs

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! We'll certainly reach out.

Comment: Hi @mac-outlook-extensibility. Any updates on this? As next quarter is almost 2 quarters away.